# Lazy loading component globally. Error on testing

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-test-utils

I'm lazy-loading a component globally like this:

```js
Vue.component(
    'TheDialog',
    () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "theDialog" */  '@/components/TheDialog')
)
```

Works fine, but when I run tests on another component, which contain `TheDialog` as a child component, I get this warning:

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

Also, I have the same error when importing a global component without lazy-loading:

```js
import TheDialog from '@/components/TheDialog'

Vue.component(
    'TheDialog', TheDialog
)
```

Does somebody know the problem?

Comment: Is that component registration in the code path of your tests?

Comment: no, its global import

Comment: But it has to be invoked from *somewhere*. How do you globally register it from your test code?

Comment: You're right! I haven't imported it in my test. But I didn't know that I need to, cause I'm using shallowMount in my test and AFAIN I don't have to import child components then.
Thanx for your help, please write your answer so I could upvote it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [`vuejs/vue-test-utils` Issue#1116](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/1116), the globally registered component would still need to be registered when using `shallowMount`.

One solution is to globally register the component on a [`localVue`](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#createlocalvue) instance:

```js
const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.component('TheDialog', TheDialog)

shallowMount(MyComponent, { localVue })
```

or you could explicitly [stub](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/#stubbing-components) it upon mounting:

```js
shallowMount(MyComponent, { stubs: ['TheDialog'] })
```

Another solution is to move your global component registrations (e.g., from `main.js`) into a separate file that could also be imported in your tests.